# Windows installation packet: msi and exe. What's difference?

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-setup

While building Visual Studio setup project it produces two files: `[ProgramName].msi` and `setup.exe`. What is the purpose of each one?

Comment: Not related to programming.

Comment: But related to "software tools commonly used by programmers", which is completely on-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSI file is the main package, that contains all the files, registry entries, custom action, etc... This is loaded by [Windows Installer service (msiexec.exe)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) and executed accordingly.

The EXE file is actually a wrapper meant to provide additional support for features not supported by Windows Installer. The most important feature is installing prerequisites. However, there other commercial setup authoring tools that include a lot more support in the EXE like compression support to minimize package size, custom UI themes, or maybe creating a single mixed package instead of two separate MSIs (x86 and x64).